# What is the principle behind the use of one LASER for optical pumping of Rubidium in presence of magnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, optical-materials, laser-interaction

How can we use a single LASER for optical pumping of rubidium in the presence of magnetic field as the zeeman levels are degenerate in the presence of magnetic field and how to decide upon the modulation frequency adequate for pumping?